# Intellij errors are not showing up in ide

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have just setup a maven project in Intelli J but no errors are showing up.

I have a project that uses Gradle and all errors are showing fine.

Comment: where do you expect them to show up? When you do a command f9 or control f9, does it do a build and show the errors?

Comment: Just when I create a new type of object that has not been included in the project. I expect them to be underlined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had not setup the project correctly. To add the maven project:

View > Tool Windows > Maven Project

Then click add maven project and select your pom.xml